# Profile picture and input disappear in mobile view

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

When I open the following layout on my computer, it is very narrow and it doesn't really fill the width of the computer.
As soon as I drag it smaller to test the resposive, I see in tablet mode that the profile part is very narrow, it should have the same size, or at least be centered. Now you can also see an error, the icon with the email, name and the name input is no longer displayed. And the button should be at the End of the height of both cards.

My question is, how do I change this so that it looks like my desired output?

I am using Bootstrap.

In the images the black color should represent the edge of the screen

Please see below for the code.

What I have:

Desktop version

[Desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxJ85.png)

Mobile version
As you can see the profilpicture, name input, ... is disappeared

[Mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE1dv.png)

What I want:

Desktop-Version
As you can see it takes almost the entire screen and is wider and has distance to the screen

[Desktop-Version - What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uhGj.png)

Tablet version
As you can see the first part should be in the middle or should be the same width

[tablet version  - what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A9Tj.png)

Mobile version

[mobile version - what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZwvK.png)

*HTML-Code*

```
<div class="body-container">
  <div className="container">
    <div class="row gutters">
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="account-settings">
              <div class="user-profile">
                <div class="user-avatar">
                  <div>
                      <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h6 class="user-email">test@email.com</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <label for="exampleInputName">Name</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Name"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Bitte geben Sie Ihren Namen an
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="about">
                <h5>Über mich</h5>
                <div class="form-group ">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea2"></label>
                  <textarea
                    class="form-control rounded-0"
                    id="exampleFormControlTextarea2"
                    rows="5"
                    placeholder="Erzähle etwas von dir"
                  ></textarea>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Der Text muss zwischen ein Zeichen und 150 Zeichen lang
                    sein.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row gutters">
              <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                <div class="pl-2">
                  <h5 class="mb-2 text-primary">
                    Persönliche Information
                  </h5>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                <div class="">
                  <div class="pl-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <label for="exampleInputWohnort">Wohnort</label>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Wohnort"
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Tragen bitte einen Ort ein.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pl-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <label for="exampleInputWohnort">Studiengang</label>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Studiengang"
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Trage bitte einen Studiengang ein.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 pl-0">
                    <div class="pl-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                          <label for="exampleInputAlter">Alter</label>
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="exampleInputPassword1"
                            placeholder="Alter"
                          />
                          <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Bitte trage ein gültiges Alter ein.
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 pl-0">
                    <div class="pl-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                          <label for="exampleInputAlter">Alter</label>
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="exampleInputPassword1"
                            placeholder="Alter"
                          />
                          <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Bitte trage ein gültiges Alter ein.
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row gutters">
              <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                <div class="text-right">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    id="submit"
                    name="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                  >
                    Speichern &amp; Weiter{" "}
                    <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Css*

```
.body-container {

   margin: 0;
   padding: 40px;
   color: #2e323c;
   background: #ffffff;
   position: relative;
   height: 100%;
    
}
.account-settings .user-profile {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.account-settings .user-profile .user-avatar {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}
.account-settings .user-profile .user-avatar img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
.account-settings .user-profile h5.user-name {
    margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
}
.account-settings .user-profile h6.user-email {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #9fa8b9;
}
.account-settings .about {
    margin: 2rem 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.account-settings .about h5 {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    color: #007ae1;
}
.account-settings .about p {
    font-size: 0.825rem;
}
.form-control {
    border: 1px solid #cfd1d8;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: .825rem;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #2e323c;
}

.card {
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.fa-user-circle{
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was you had `className` for your container class attribute, rather than `class,` so the container style wasn’t getting included.

Also, you had a duplicate ID and some of the input labels are incorrect (and one input had `itemref` instead of `id`).

I did play with your column classes – You don’t need to specify column sizes for every breakpoint, just when you want a change.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .body-container {

        margin: 0;
        padding: 40px;
        color: #2e323c;
        background: #ffffff;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;

    }

    .account-settings .user-profile {
        margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .account-settings .user-profile .user-avatar {
        margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
    }

    .account-settings .user-profile .user-avatar img {
        -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
        -moz-border-radius: 100px;
        border-radius: 100px;
    }

    .account-settings .user-profile h5.user-name {
        margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
    }

    .account-settings .user-profile h6.user-email {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #9fa8b9;
    }

    .account-settings .about {
        margin: 2rem 0 0 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .account-settings .about h5 {
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
        color: #007ae1;
    }

    .account-settings .about p {
        font-size: 0.825rem;
    }

    .form-control {
        border: 1px solid #cfd1d8;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        font-size: .825rem;
        background: #ffffff;
        color: #2e323c;
    }

    .card {
        background: #ffffff;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 0;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    .fa-user-circle {
        font-size: 100px;
    }
</style>

<div class="body-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row gutters">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 offset-lg-1">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="account-settings">
                            <div class="user-profile">
                                <div class="user-avatar">
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <h6 class="user-email">test@email.com</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <label for="exampleInputName">Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Name" />
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            Bitte geben Sie Ihren Namen an
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="about">
                                <h5>Über mich</h5>
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea2"></label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="exampleFormControlTextarea2" rows="5" placeholder="Erzähle etwas von dir"></textarea>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Der Text muss zwischen ein Zeichen und 150 Zeichen lang
                                        sein.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-7">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row gutters">
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                <div class="pl-2">
                                    <h5 class="mb-2 text-primary">
                                        Persönliche Information
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                <div class="">
                                    <div class="pl-2">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                <label for="exampleInputWohnort">Wohnort</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputWohnort" placeholder="Wohnort" />
                                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                    Tragen bitte einen Ort ein.
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pl-2">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                <label for="exampleInputWohnort1">Studiengang</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputWohnort1" placeholder="Studiengang" />
                                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                    Trage bitte einen Studiengang ein.
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 pl-0">
                                        <div class="pl-2">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Alter</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Alter" />
                                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                        Bitte trage ein gültiges Alter ein.
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 pl-0">
                                        <div class="pl-2">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword2">Alter</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Alter" />
                                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                        Bitte trage ein gültiges Alter ein.
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row gutters">
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                <div class="text-right">
                                    <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Speichern &amp; Weiter{" "}
                                        <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```